# how to convert -negative values in strings to double

Tags: java, android

i need to read the values from a file(.csv) ,which contains both positive and negative values.. i am getting an error while converting string to integer.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(getAssets().open("Book1.csv")).useDelimiter(",");
    int i = 0;
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String str  = sc.next();
        data[i] = new GraphViewData(i, Integer.parseInt(str));
        i++;
    }
```

Below is my logcat :

```
05-02 04:05:55.119: E/AndroidRuntime(3003): ' as integer
05-02 04:05:55.119: E/AndroidRuntime(3003):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-02 04:05:55.119: E/AndroidRuntime(3003):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-02 04:05:55.119: E/AndroidRuntime(3003):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-02 04:05:55.119: E/AndroidRuntime(3003):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-02 04:05:55.119: E/AndroidRuntime(3003):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-02 04:05:55.119: E/AndroidRuntime(3003):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-02 04:05:55.119: E/AndroidRuntime(3003):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-02 04:05:55.119: E/AndroidRuntime(3003):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 04:05:55.119: E/AndroidRuntime(3003):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-02 04:05:55.119: E/AndroidRuntime(3003):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-02 04:05:55.119: E/AndroidRuntime(3003):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-02 04:05:55.119: E/AndroidRuntime(3003):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 04:05:55.119: E/AndroidRuntime(3003): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '893
```

Comment: what exception you are getting?

Comment: Have you tried printing out str and verifying that it is a valid number?

Comment: i print the str before converting the vales ..it's printed total values

Comment: look at the stacktrace: it says "unable to parse '893" so remove ' before passing the string to parseInt

Comment: actually problem is your `Str` also contain non-number text that cause problem make filter for that.

Comment: wheni print the str values i got the all values in the file

Comment: actually there is nothing wrong with the numbers ,it doesn't contain ' or " .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert negative values in strings to Integer you can use Integer.parseInt as you show in your code.

I don't think the error you are seeing is to do with the minus sign - it's ok to pass a string that starts with an ASCII minus sign (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

BTW - are you trying to convert to Integer or Double? your question title mentions Double (Double.parseDouble also accepts the sign)

Answer (score 2):

You could something like this

```
String negNum = "-743.347";
Double num = Double.valueOf(negNum);
System.out.println("Negative number: " + num);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Integer.parseInt` should work for negative numbers. However, note that you could have written the negative number as follows `- 3` instead of just `-3`. The extra space will cause the parsing to fail. You will need to make sure that you are actually trying to parse actual numbers without any other strings in them.

You could use something like so `Integer.parseInt(str.replaceAll("[^\\d-]+", ""));` to remove all non numeric data.

EDIT: As per your exception, you seem to have an extra *`* in your string, which is causing the conversion to fail. Please make sure that you only have numbers when you try and parse strings to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this...

```
Math.abs(x)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. `Math.abs` takes a double, and the question is about parsing a `String` into a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

The minus sign imported from the csv file of yours is of another ASCII. A simple and fast way is to:

```
str = str.replaceAll("−", "-")
```